# In memory which supports Oracle "schema.package.function(IN, OUT)"

Tags: sqlite, h2, derby, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I have to write JUnit test cases for REST API created using Spring boot and Oracle. There is no dedicated test DB environment. So I planned to use the in-memory database. I did a POC on H2 database. Even after spending 3 days, I was able to do basic things but it is not fully compatible with Oracle. It didn't support In, Out parameter, also it didn't support "call schema.package.function(In, Out)". I was able to create schema and function but I was not able to create a package. Could you please suggest an in-memory which support the following

1. Should support schema, package and function creation.
2. Should support In, Out parameter
3. Should be lightweight
4. Should be compatible with Oracle and Java

Comment: You should test using the same database you use in production. Set up an Oracle db for test purposes.

Comment: Derby is **not** compatible with Oracle. Derby **is** SQL-Standards compliant, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSQLDB supports IN and OUT parameters for PROCEDURES. You can mimic the schema.package.function(in, out) by renaming the database CATALOG as the name of the schema and creating a separate schema named as the package, then creating the function in that schema.

Alternatively, HyperXtremeSQL (http://hyperxtreme.co.uk) supports creation of package, procedure and function with Oracle syntax.

Comment: From my business layer I call multiple DAO layers.  Each is in different schema and different package. How to handle this scenario. It is working for one DAO layer but how to make it work for multiple DAO layers.   (DAO1 -> schema1.package1.function1, DAO2 -> schema2.package2.function2). Right now I am doing ALTER CATALOG PUBLIC RENAME TO SCHEMA1, CREATE SCHEMA PACKAGE. This works for unit testing but how to make it working for integration testing. Can we have multiple CATALOG?

Comment: You cannot do multiple packages in HSQLDB.